# Loading a Zend Form via Ajax Call

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, zend-framework

I have a requirement to load a form into a page dynamically, with the potential for multiple instances of this form. Validating and saving is not a problem, but I cannot seem to pass back the actual form content / mark-up from the Controller. When testing with simple values (id: 1) I can return the data successfully, but the actual form is always returned as undefined if the datatype is not set, or [Object object].

Controller:

```
public function addPermissionFormAction()
{
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
    //data from ajax call is successfully received
    $username = $this->getRequest()->getParam('user');
    //...Code to get $pages...
    $form = new Pds_Wizard_SubForm_Externals($pages);

    if(!isset($form)) $form = false;
    //I have run XDebug to here and confirmed that the form is built successfully.
    echo Zend_Json::encode(array('form' => $form));
}
```

My Ajax Call:

```
$('#get-player-permissions').click(function() {
    if($('#test-test').val().length > 0) {
        $.ajax({
        url: '/pds/external-user/add-permission-form',
        data: { user: $('#test-test').val() },
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(data){
            alert(data.form); // [Object object]
            $("#wizardContainer").html(data.form); //empty, no form content
        }
    })
    } 
});
```

I have tried this without even adding the **dataType** or **contentType** fields for sending simple values, and have no issue getting those through. With the form, however, I will get a null or undefined in this case.

Any advice is appreciated, including more ideal methods of dynamically loading a form. I do not use Ajax calls very often, so if this is a simple mistake I apologize. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What does `alert(JSON.stringify(data.form))` show?

Comment: You can't set "no render" in this case. You need to have a view "add-permission-form.phtml" (or another view specified) to format and display the HTML code

Comment: {}

Just empty brackets. I haven't used stringify before, is it recommended over just alert(data)?

Comment: sdespont: If that is the case, I am assuming I would pass the form to it via $this->view->form = $form. Having said that, is the entire viewscript what gets returned to the Ajax Success?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't set "no render" in this case. You need to have a view "add-permission-form.phtml" (or another view specified) to format and display the HTML code

**Controller :**

```
public function addPermissionFormAction()
{
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();

    //data from ajax call is successfully received
    $username = $this->getRequest()->getParam('user');
    //...Code to get $pages...
    $form = new Pds_Wizard_SubForm_Externals($pages);

    if(!isset($form)) $form = false;
    //I have run XDebug to here and confirmed that the form is built successfully.
    echo Zend_Json::encode(array('form' => $form));

    //Assign the form to a variable view
    $this->view->form = $form;
}
```

**View : add-permission-form.phtml :**

```
<?php echo $this->form ;?>
```

**Ajax call :**

No comment, your code look cool

Comment: First off, thank you for the quick response!

I've added the viewscript, but I'm curious how this will be returned to the Ajax call...will **data** simply be the entire view-script?

Comment: If you set "no render" there will not render anything. If you don't set "no render" you must provide a view script to render your code. You can't just echo some code from the controller called by an AJAX code, even if you can do that durring the whole page displaying, it is an antipattern.

Comment: Removing the 'no render', replacing the echo Json with $this->view->form = $form, and adding the view-script causes the view-script to be returned properly, and anything I add in that view-script EXCEPT the form will show up. The form itself still gets lost in translation somehow...Should I be returning this in some other format, or setting the content type?

Comment: I figured out that the form wasn't rendering properly due to someone forgetting to commit a single line out of the custom constructor! SIGH!

Thank you very much for your help in setting the correct process for the ajax call, however. greatly appreciated.